# android keyboard blocking EditText

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

After an EditText control gets focus, the soft keyboard displays, if the control is below half of the screen, the keyboard will block it from allowing user to input.

I did some search, adding windowSoftInputMode (both tried adjustPan and adjustResize) for the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file will solve the blocking issue, but all input controls look awful, e.g., the single line text will have gray background and black border, and radio button will have dark thick border and green inside, and the focused multi line EditBox will have complete black background.

Any idea how to solve the issue (not blocking input and without those awful controls.)

1. "Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" as default theme.
2. Android 4.1.x

Comment: _may be_ scrollview help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the following line in your manifest inside the activity tag. It will work.

```
<activity
    android:name="Your activity name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Even then if any problem, you can use scrollview along with this.

Comment: it will not block the user input, but it makes all editable controls looks awful, mentioned above.

Comment: I found the problem and solved finally. Yes, we can use "adjustPan", but we need to apply the theme to the manifest file, as it overwrites the one we declare in the activity class.

Comment: Ya you have to declare the theme in manifest. Anyway, glad it worked:)

Answer (score 0):

Just take out the top constraints for the edit text in the activity file