# Keyboard keeps blocking my view... how to fix it?

Tags: android, user-interface, interface

my keyboard keeps blocking my view. Is there anyway to fix this?

[image]

When I click the Description 2 to insert something, But the keyboard so annoying... I can't see what I'm typing... Actually This isn't one page. Others page also like this. I can't see what I'm typing, Only when I close the keyboard then okay can see the things.

[image]

**Here is the code**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|top">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"></ListView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="DATE:" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Select_Date"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="38dp"
                    android:text="SELECT DATE"
                    android:textSize="19dp"
                    />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TXN NO:" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/D_Txn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="NAME:" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/D_Name"
                    android:layout_width="273dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />
            </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="72dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="AMOUNT:" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/D_Amount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="number" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="DESCRIPTION1:" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/D_Description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="DESCRIPTION2:" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/Ds_Description"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />


            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:textColor="@color/my_color_state"
                    android:id="@+id/Db_New"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="NEW" />

                <Button
                    android:textColor="@color/my_color_state"
                    android:id="@+id/Db_Save"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:text=   "SAVE" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:textColor="@color/my_color_state"
                    android:id="@+id/Db_Print"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="PRINT" />

                <Button
                    android:textColor="@color/my_color_state"
                    android:id="@+id/Db_Back"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="BACK" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android keyboard blocking EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348657/android-keyboard-blocking-edittext)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest, add this line to your activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

It adjusts your activity when the available layout size changes.

**EDIT:**

You'll also have to add a `ScrollView` over the main container in your case.

Comment: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` Is not working. If I put `ScrollView` the app will crash...

Comment: When I click the EditText and going to type something. But the keyboard blocks the EditText. So I can't see the EditText.... I don't know how to explain it. But Sometimes I use some of the apps. Click the EditText. and the keyboard pops out and the EditText is at the above of the keyboard, Then I won't block the EditText. You get it?

Comment: Yes, I know what your problem is. But a ScrollView allows you at least to scroll in the Layout when it's too big.

Comment: you can reach me on Twitter: @antitized

Comment: check it. Thanks @Antonio

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Manifest and add this line for the selected activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Example:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

Comment: Then you have some other wrong setting. I'm working on an app which have this feature and works perfectly